# ReactNative Alert.alert() dialog doesn't trigger onDismiss event when dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, react-native

React-Native Alert.alert() dialog doesn't trigger onDismiss event when dialog is closed.

I've put the onDismiss object where it is supposed to be according to the documentation.

```
Alert.alert(
        'Confirm Order',
        'Are you sure you want to place this order ?',
        [
          {
            text: 'No',
            onPress: () => console.log('No'),
            style: 'cancel'
          },
          { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Yes') }
        ],
        { cancelable: true },
        {
          onDismiss: () => {
            console.log(Dismissed')
          }
        }
      )
```

I expect to see "Dismissed" in the console when the dialog is dismissed, but I don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

> By default alerts on Android can be dismissed by tapping outside of the alert box. This event can be handled by providing an optional options parameter, with an onDismiss callback property { onDismiss: () => {} }.

From [React Alert Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert)

onDismiss should be a callback property.
Update the code like so

```
Alert.alert(
        'Confirm Order',
        'Are you sure you want to place this order ?',
        [
          {
            text: 'No',
            onPress: () => console.log('No'),
            style: 'cancel'
          },
          { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Yes') }
        ],
        { cancelable: true,
          onDismiss: () => { //move the object
            console.log(Dismissed')
          }
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that the `onDismiss` has to go inside the same `options` object as the `cancelable` property:

```
Alert.alert(
        'Confirm Order',
        'Are you sure you want to place this order ?',
        [
          {
            text: 'No',
            onPress: () => console.log('No'),
            style: 'cancel'
          },
          { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Yes') }
        ],
        { cancelable: true, // add onDismiss after this line
          onDismiss: () => {
            console.log(Dismissed')
          }
        },
      )
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was putting the onDismiss event at the wrong place. Thanks @Marcel Kalveram

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Alert.alert(
      'Confirm Order',
      'Are you sure you want to place this order ?',
      [
        {
          text: 'No',
          onPress:() => console.log('No'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        { 
          text: 'Yes', 
          onPress: () => console.log('Yes'),
        }
      ],
      {
        onDismiss: () => console.log('Dismiss')
      }
    );
```